# change CFS scheduler variables

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, scheduler, cfs

Today I wanted to change the timeslice for the CFS scheduler, So, I decided to change the below variables(parameters):

`kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns`

`kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns`

`kernel.sched_latency_ns`

Now, on my ZORIN OS, I can see these variables using `sysctl -A | grep shced` and therefore I can change it since these files are available in `/proc/sys/kernel` However, on my `ubuntu 20.04`, there aren't such those files! And therefore, I can't create or change those parameters.

**My question is that**, How can I change these parameters in `ubuntu 20.04`, and why aren't those parameters available?